# MySQL - Complex hierarchical relationships - multiple M:N?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL query which is used with PHP to build hierarchical JSON for a d3.js tree/dendrogram.

See [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3xy96hwyCcd4n6jSBLFx52/2) for schema and existing query.

I'm now looking at how I can add an additional data relationship between program_outcome data, **O**, and unit data, **U**, with development_level data, **D**, in between as a many to many relationship.

There are only three types of **D** as you can see in the diagram below.

Conceptual diagram of what I need:

[image]

Each **U** will be related to only one **D** per **O** (only one **O** branch shown for clarity).

So U needs to be a child of **D** and a grandchild of **O**.  For other **O** branches, the same **U** may have the same or different type of **D**.

As you can see in the fiddle, the relationship between **O** and **U** is currently through a lookup/relational table `program_outcome_unit_lookup`.

Also, there is the possibility of changing the lookup table, so instead of having `program_outcome_unit_lookup` table, there could be two lookup tables, which might work:

**O** -> **U**

**D** -> **U**

Any ideas how this would be achieved?

The PHP after the query (not in the db fiddle...) is following, but may not be relevant to a solution, which is essentially a DB problem.

```
$result = $connection->query($query);
$data = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
    $data[$row->global_id] = $row;
}

$roots = array();
foreach ($data as $row) {   
    $row->type = end(explode(",",(implode(array_slice(explode ( ':',  $row->global_id), -2, 1)))));
    if ($row->parent_global_id === null) {
        $roots[]= $row;
    } else {
        $data[$row->parent_global_id]->children[] = $row;
    }
    unset($row->parent_global_id);
    unset($row->global_id);
}

$json = json_encode($roots);

$json = trim($json, '[]');

$fp = fopen('data.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, $json);
fclose($fp);
```

**UPDATE**

See the expanded conceptual diagram with two branches:

[image]

Comment: Does your MySQL version is really 5.7 like in your fiddle?

Comment: *how I can add an additional data relationship between program_outcome data, O, and unit data, U, with development_level data, D, in between as a many to many relationship.* Many-to-many relationship links strictly two entities whereas you want to link three ones. Either you need to have a relation which links all three entities (but in this case it is not M:N) or you must create M:N for two of these entities (which become intermediate fake entity) and then link third entity to this relation as M:N. The scheme which you must to use depends on the meaning of your data.

Comment: @akina  Yep, 5.7, but I'm planning to upgrade, it's a university scenario and MySQL is not actually supported.  So I must upgrade by myself, and currently there is no need - but i's in the pipeline with a RHEL8 upgrade enforced by IT....

Comment: @akina  Re the M:N scenario, currently a M:N exists O -> U via the program_outcome_unit_lookup table.  As I want to add another level between those, I just don't know what that table structure might look like.  Since all O will have all three types of  D, having that table lookup O -> D seems unnecessary and somewhat onerous.  Perhaps this could be done simply in the PHP?

Comment: *Since all O will have all three types of D* ?? Will have? or must have? Is it possible that an instance of O entity is related to only one or two instances of D entity, or it must refer to three instances of D entity strictly? PS. As I understand the O cannot refer to more than three D. If so then we have one relation 1:3 (or maybe 1:(0-3), or another).

Comment: @akina  In this particular scenario, all O will have all three types of D.  However, in a different scenario (if that eventuates), that may not be the case.  Irrespective, each O, jn this scenario, will have each type of D, ie all three.

Comment: Note that I have updated the OP re the two lookup tables possibility which is different.

Comment: If your graph is 1:n while you are (or seem to be) asking about m:n, I don't think "only one O branch shown for clarity" provides clarity. Also, if D is a child of O and U is a child of D, why do you propose O->U and D->U instead of O->D and D->U? There seem to be something missing in your description (that at least i dont get). Is this a new project for you/are you new to sql? In that case, it might be that the problem is actually trivial, but you may not see the wood for the trees (need m:n? Then add a junction table. Done.). If not, you probably have to explain the problem better.

Comment: @Solarflare  The added expanded conceptual diagram to the OP may help.  I don't think O->D and D->U would work as it's a more of a three way relationship.

Comment: Thanks, I think it cleared it up, I added an answer (and I hope I understood your task correctly now).

Comment: How many nodes are we talking about?  (Perhaps a simple tuple would suffice.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model seems to be: each (unique) tuple `(O, U)` is assigned a mandatory value `D`.

You can implement this model by adding a column `D` to your  `program_outcome_unit_lookup` table:

```
CREATE TABLE `program_outcome_unit_lookup` (
  `program_outcome_unit_lookup_pk` int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `program_outcome_fk` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `devdata_fk` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `unit_fk` int(2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`program_outcome_unit_lookup_pk`),
  UNIQUE KEY (`program_outcome_fk`, `unit_fk`)
);
```

`(program_outcome_fk, unit_fk)` could be your primary key as well, but either way it has to be unique (you are currently not enforcing this constraint).

Now each `U` can be member of as many `O` as you like, but "each `U` will be related to only one `D` per `O`", as requested.

To e.g. store `U1` from your updated graph (`O1-D2-U1` and `O2-D1-U1`), you would add into `(O,D,U)` the values `((1,2,1),(2,1,1))`. As requested, you cannot also add e.g. `O2-D2-U1`, as it would violate the unique constraint.

You should also add a new table for `D`. If not every `D` is allowed for every `O` (e.g. if `O2` branches are not allowed to use `D1`), you will also need a table `(O, D)`, otherwise it is not necessary.

Comment: Looks like a possible solution, thanks.  Would you put this into a fork of my DB fiddle with an updated version of my query?

Comment: I am glad it solved your modelling problem, but sorry, I won't adjust a 100 line query that literally just defines how you like your output. There is absolutely no trick to it, it's just work that takes some time; no future reader of this question gains anything from someone else doing that job for you, and it probably actually takes you more time to explain the exact output you want than to add the column+join and adjust the texts yourself. If you run into problems doing it, of course feel free to ask.

Comment: OK, thanks.  I'll see how I go!